# Custom Membership with Microsoft.AspNet.Identity - CreateLocalUser fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, owin, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I've been trying to implement a custom version of the new Identity features in ASP.NET 4.5 (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity), using Visual Studio 2013.  After many hours of playing around with this, I've simplified my code in an effort to get it running without errors.  I've listed my code below.  When doing a Local Registration, the database tables are created, but the CreateLocalUser method fails.  I'm hoping that someone can help me identify the changes needed.

### Models/MembershipModel.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace thePulse.web.Models
{
    public class PulseUser : IUser
    {
        public PulseUser() { }
        public PulseUser(string userName) 
        {
            UserName = userName;
        }

        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        [StringLength(1)]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }

    public class PulseUserClaim : IUserClaim
    {
        public PulseUserClaim() { }

        [Key]
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string ClaimType { get; set; }
        public string ClaimValue { get; set; }

    }

    public class PulseUserSecret : IUserSecret
    {
        public PulseUserSecret() { }
        public PulseUserSecret(string userName, string secret)
        {
            UserName = userName;
            Secret = secret;
        }

        [Key]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Secret { get; set; }

    }

    public class PulseUserLogin : IUserLogin
    {
        public PulseUserLogin() { }
        public PulseUserLogin(string userId, string loginProvider, string providerKey) 
        {
            LoginProvider = LoginProvider;
            ProviderKey = providerKey;
            UserId = userId;
        }

        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public string ProviderKey { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }

    public class PulseRole : IRole
    {
        public PulseRole() { }
        public PulseRole(string roleId)
        {
            Id = roleId;
        }

        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class PulseUserRole : IUserRole
    {
        public PulseUserRole() { }

        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public string RoleId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }

    public class PulseUserContext : IdentityStoreContext
    {
        public PulseUserContext(DbContext db) : base(db)
        {
            Users = new UserStore<PulseUser>(db);
            Logins = new UserLoginStore<PulseUserLogin>(db);
            Roles = new RoleStore<PulseRole, PulseUserRole>(db);
            Secrets = new UserSecretStore<PulseUserSecret>(db);
            UserClaims = new UserClaimStore<PulseUserClaim>(db);
        }
    }

    public class PulseDbContext : IdentityDbContext<PulseUser, PulseUserClaim, PulseUserSecret, PulseUserLogin, PulseRole, PulseUserRole>
    {
    }
}
```

### Changes to Controllers/AccountController.cs

```
public AccountController() 
{

    IdentityStore = new IdentityStoreManager(new PulseUserContext(new PulseDbContext()));
    AuthenticationManager = new IdentityAuthenticationManager(IdentityStore);
}

//
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a profile, password, and link the local login before signing in the user
            PulseUser user = new PulseUser(model.UserName);
            if (await IdentityStore.CreateLocalUser(user, model.Password))
            {
                await AuthenticationManager.SignIn(HttpContext, user.Id, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed to register user name: " + model.UserName);
            }
        }
        catch (IdentityException e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

As I said above, this implementation fails when the CreateLocalUser method fails (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework).  I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Here's a sample Identity application that is doing something similar to what I'm doing (for reference).
https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample/tree/master/AspnetIdentitySample

Comment: And here's a post from the MSDN Blogs describing the new Identity system for ASP.NET.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx

Comment: I also have not been able to implement this. Ive not found any examples which work with a custom User table containing the password, but also allow the oAuth capabilites of linking google etc accounts to the same record in the database.

Comment: Phil, the following line (in the AccountController) is returning a false, and no User record is created in the database.

if (await IdentityStore.CreateLocalUser(user, model.Password))

Comment: Here's another page reviewing the new OWIN Forms Autentication:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5.aspx

Comment: Can you also add the code for the DbContext, there might be issues there.

Comment: Hao Kung, the dbContext code is included at the bottom of the MembershipModels.cs file.  Am I missing something else?

Comment: What version is this related to. Will i face the samme issues if I try above on release candidate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue here is that IdentityStoreManager has strong dependency on the default implementation of identity EF models. For example, the CreateLocalUser method will create  UserSecret and UserLogin objects and save them to stores, which won't work if the store is not using the default model type. So if you customize the model type, it won't work smoothly with IdentityStoreManager.

Since you only customize the IUser model, I simplified the code to inherit custom user from default identity user and reuse other models from identity EF models.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication11.Models
{
    public class PulseUser : User
    {
        public PulseUser() { }
        public PulseUser(string userName) : base(userName)
        {
        }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        [StringLength(1)]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }

    public class PulseUserContext : IdentityStoreContext
    {
        public PulseUserContext(DbContext db) : base(db)
        {
            this.Users = new UserStore<PulseUser>(this.DbContext);
        }
    }

    public class PulseDbContext : IdentityDbContext<PulseUser, UserClaim, UserSecret, UserLogin, Role, UserRole>
    {
    }
}
```

The code above should work with preview version of Identity API.

The IdentityStoreManager API in upcoming release is already aware of this issue and changed all the non-EF dependency code into a base class so that you can customize it by inheriting from it. It should solve all the problems here. Thanks.

Comment: [@Hongye Sun] What versions of identity store are you referring to when you say preview? i am currently referencing 1.0.0-beta1? Does this implementation allow the user and password for the local account to be in the custom user table, and also allow for implementation of additional oauth providers?

Comment: Thank you, Hongye Sun.  I'll definitely be looking forward to the released version of this, as it's pretty much unusable for any large user base.

Comment: Should I be able to get it working Implementing IUser? or should i always do myuser:User?

Answer (score 1):

PulseUser.Id is defined as a string but doesn't appear to be set to a value.  Were you meant to be using a GUID for the Id?  If so, initialise it in the constructor.

```
    public PulseUser() : this(String.Empty) { }
    public PulseUser(string userName) 
    {
        UserName = userName;
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
```

You will also want to perform a check that the user name doesn't already exist.  Look at overriding DbEntityValidationResult in PulseDbContext.  Do a new MVC project in VS2013 to see an example.

Comment: Thanks, Grant. I definitely missed that.  However, I'm still getting the same error message, and haven't progressed any further.

Comment: To clarify, I'm dropping all tables in the database each time I publish any code changes.  I then attempt to do a Local Registration with a simple UserName ("Vito") and a password.  It fails to create the User each time.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are alot of changes on this when going to RTM, i have updated the SPA template that uses a WebApi controller for all the identity signin and such. Its a really cool template , if you havent seen it.

I put all my code here:
https://github.com/s093294/aspnet-identity-rtm/tree/master

(Do note, its only for inspiration. I only made it work and nothing more. Properly have a bug or two also).