# MVC 5 custom user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication

So I have been playing with MVC 5 recently and I love it.
I have come across something that I thought would be simple to do, but has ended up eating into hours of my day and I am none the wiser.

Basically I want to extend the **User** model by adding my own properties. I did this:

```
public class IdentityUser : User
{
    public IdentityUser()
    //: this(String.Empty)
    {
    }

    public IdentityUser(string userName)
        : base(userName)
    {
    }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredTitle")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredFirstName")]
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredLastName")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredUserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredEmail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string LinkedIn { get; set; }
    public string Twitter { get; set; }
    public string Facebook { get; set; }
    public string Google { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredCredentialId")]
    public string CredentialId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredSecurityCode")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Can only edit own assets")]
    public bool UserCanEditOwn { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Can edit assets")]
    public bool UserCanEdit { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Can download assets")]
    public bool UserCanDownload { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Require approval to upload assets")]
    public bool UserRequiresApproval { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Can approve assets")]
    public bool UserCanApprove { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Can synchronise assets")]
    public bool UserCanSync { get; set; }

    public bool AgreedTerms { get; set; }
}

public class IdentityUserContext : IdentityStoreContext
{
    public IdentityUserContext(DbContext db)
        : base(db)
    {
        this.Users = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(this.DbContext);
    }
}

public class IdentityUserDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, UserClaim, UserSecret, UserLogin, Role, UserRole>
{
}
```

**User** is the default User class in EF

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
{
    public class User : IUser
    {
    public User();
    public User(string userName);

    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have inherited it because I read somewhere that you have to do that if you want to use a custom class.
Anyway, I then changed my Register model to look like this:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CredentialId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

and the method to look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a profile, password, and link the local login before signing in the user
            var companyId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var user = new IdentityUser( model.UserName)
            {
                CompanyId = companyId,
                Title = model.Title,
                Forename = model.Forename,
                Surname = model.Surname,
                Email = model.Email,
                CompanyName = model.CompanyName,
                CredentialId = model.CredentialId
            };

            if (await IdentityStore.CreateLocalUser(user, model.Password))
            {
                await AuthenticationManager.SignIn(HttpContext, user.Id, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Setup", new { id = user.CompanyId });
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed to register user name: " + model.UserName);
            }
        }
        catch (IdentityException e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

When I try to register I get this error:

```
Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'TestProject.Models.IdentityUser'.
```

I can't figure out why.

Am I missing a step or something?

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please less abstract code, more concrete code. And more meaningful title!

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: Are you sure all code is related to the question? And 100% question title is meaningless. Use 5-7 words fully describing your issue.

Comment: yeah of course, everything is relevant

Comment: But title is still 100% meaningless. Please fix it today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to this post:

[Custom Membership with Microsoft.AspNet.Identity - CreateLocalUser fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911430/custom-membership-with-microsoft-aspnet-identity-createlocaluser-fails)

My class now looks like this:

```
public class User : IUser
{
    public User()
    {
        this.LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        this.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public User(string userName)
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        this.UserName = userName;

        this.CreatedBy = this.Id;

        this.LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        this.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;

        this.IsApproved = true;
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredUserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required] public string CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required] public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredTitle")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredFirstName")]
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredLastName")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredEmail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string LinkedIn { get; set; }
    public string Twitter { get; set; }
    public string Facebook { get; set; }
    public string Google { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredCredentialId")]
    public string CredentialId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredSecurityCode")]
    public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Can only edit own assets")]
    public bool CanEditOwn { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Can edit assets")]
    public bool CanEdit { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Can download assets")]
    public bool CanDownload { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Require approval to upload assets")]
    public bool RequiresApproval { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Can approve assets")]
    public bool CanApprove { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Can synchronise assets")]
    public bool CanSync { get; set; }

    public bool AgreedTerms { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}

public class UserContext : IdentityStoreContext
{
    public UserContext(DbContext db)
        : base(db)
    {
        this.Users = new UserStore<User>(this.DbContext);
    }
}

public class UserDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, UserClaim, UserSecret, UserLogin, Role, UserRole>
{
}
```

and in my AccountController constructor I have this:

```
    public AccountController() 
    {
        IdentityStore = new IdentityStoreManager(new UserContext(new UserDbContext()));
        AuthenticationManager = new IdentityAuthenticationManager(IdentityStore);
    }
```

and that is it, everything works as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

You can merge IdentityUser and User. As long as it inherits from IUser, you should be OK.

Maybe start with that.

Edit:

Here's the user class that i'm currently using and storing it using EF Code First.

```
public class User : IUser
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set;}

    [Required]
    public UserType UserType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Merge how? Originally I had identity user implementing IUser but it didn't work. I read the solution was to inherit User from EF

Comment: Can you show me what your AccountController constructor looks like please?

Answer (score 0):

How about add a cast?

```
IdentityStore.CreateLocalUser(user as User, model.Password)
```