# MVC 5 GetUserId() returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity

I have created a custom **User** class implementing **IUser**.
When I register everything completes fine, the tables are created (if they don't exist) and all looks ok, but, as the subject states, I cannot get User.GetUserId() to work.
It always returns null which is really annoying.

Here is my User class:

```
public class User : IUser
{
    public User()
    {
        this.LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        this.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public User(string userName)
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        this.UserName = userName;

        this.CreatedBy = this.Id;

        this.LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        this.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;

        this.IsApproved = true;
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredUserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required] public string CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required] public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredTitle")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredFirstName")]
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredLastName")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredEmail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string LinkedIn { get; set; }
    public string Twitter { get; set; }
    public string Facebook { get; set; }
    public string Google { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredCredentialId")]
    public string CredentialId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredSecurityCode")]
    public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Can only edit own assets")]
    public bool CanEditOwn { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Can edit assets")]
    public bool CanEdit { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Can download assets")]
    public bool CanDownload { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Require approval to upload assets")]
    public bool RequiresApproval { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Can approve assets")]
    public bool CanApprove { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Can synchronise assets")]
    public bool CanSync { get; set; }

    public bool AgreedTerms { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}

public class UserContext : IdentityStoreContext
{
    public UserContext(DbContext db)
        : base(db)
    {
        this.Users = new UserStore<User>(this.DbContext);
    }
}

public class UserDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, UserClaim, UserSecret, UserLogin, Role, UserRole>
{
}
```

Here is my Register function:

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a profile, password, and link the local login before signing in the user
                var companyId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var user = new Skipstone.Models.User(model.UserName)
                {
                    CompanyId = companyId,
                    Title = model.Title,
                    Forename = model.Forename,
                    Surname = model.Surname,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    CompanyName = model.CompanyName,
                    CredentialId = model.CredentialId
                };

                if (await IdentityStore.CreateLocalUser(user, model.Password))
                {
                    // Create our company
                    var company = new Company()
                    {
                        Id = companyId,
                        CreatedBy = user.Id,
                        ModifiedBy = user.Id,
                        Name = model.CompanyName
                    };

                    using (var service = new CompanyService())
                    {
                        service.Save(company);
                    }

                    await AuthenticationManager.SignIn(HttpContext, user.Id, isPersistent: false);

                    var test = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; // returns true
                    var u = User.Identity.GetUserId(); // returns null

                    return RedirectToAction("Setup", new { id = companyId });
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed to register user name: " + model.UserName);
                }
            }
            catch (IdentityException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

var test returns true, so it knows the user is now logged in.
var u is null, so User.Identity.GetUserId() is not working as it should.

Does anyone have any idea why?

I can post more code on request :)

**Update 1**

By creating a fresh project and testing with defaults, I have found that called **User.Identity** returns null when in the **Register** method.

But in the fresh project, calling it anywhere else returns the right information, but in my project I get null for everything.

**Update 2**

It is definately related to the custom **User** class.
I created one on my fresh project and the same thing happens.
So, something is wrong :) now I just have to figure out what!?!

Comment: Is the userId updated after calling "IdentityStore.CreateLocalUser"?

Comment: I have updated my question. In answer to yours, the userId (Id) is created in the line User(username) as a Guid

Comment: I suppose, you have to notify framework how Id field is called in your User class

Comment: I have solved it using this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911430/custom-membership-with-microsoft-aspnet-identity-createlocaluser-fails

Comment: it is not exactly what I want, but it allows me to save my custom fields to the database. I still have to use my repository to get them back though :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume somewhere in your project there is a row of database connection initialization, something like this:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true)
```

So, make sure that you use "Id" instead of "UserId" in this line